# Energy consumption of mathematical operations

Tags: pcb, math, power-consumption

Are there any general estimates of the (relative) power consumption of mathematical operations in electronic circuits? Surely, this is chip-dependent, but for example, `exp(x)` and `log(x)` seem to be universally much more computationally heavy than power (`x^2`, `sqrt(x)`) and addition/subtraction because the former is approximated via iteration/expansion.

The context of this question is that I was having a discussion with a colleague about whether to update a computation to include the term `exp(x)` rather than just `x` and it will run approximately once per second when the chip is non-sleeping. This is part of a larger battery-powered electronic unit that has two piezo actuators, sensors, and several other components. The argument came up that the extra energy consumption of computing `exp(x)` each second would significantly reduce battery lifetime.

The precision needed is only around four significant digits. Unfortunately, I don't know what chip used in this particular instance, but it's relatively low-level. It runs on a battery for 10+ years and can do linear interpolation and multiplication. But since I can't find a single number on the cost of computing e.g. `exp(5.24)` for any chip out there, it's hard to assess the problem of whether it will substantially drain the battery.

Comment: It boils down to what current the CPU takes when idling versus what current it takes when executing code and how much longer it stays executing code when it could be idling.

Comment: You need to add more details. Which microcontroller do you use? At which speed? Is it idle or in sleep-mode when not doing calculations?

Comment: Jonas how many exp() per second do you calculate, to which accuracy, on which data type, with which latency, using which hardware constraints? There's no general "exp(x) takes roughly this much energy", because there's totally different implementations of exp(x), all with different energy/throughput/latency/size/accuracy/… tradeoffs.

Comment: On which device the algorithm runs? There is a big difference if it is an ARM CPU with hardware floating point unit and good math library using it, or simple 8-bit MCU without even hardware multiplier and inefficient floating point math library.

Comment: still missing the data type (floating or fixed point, number of bits) and the processor type, Jonas, as well as the math library or exp implementation you're using.

Comment: I've updated the question with (1) it doesn't break sleeping, (2) only four significant digits are needed, (3) what I know about the processor. Maybe it's not enough, but my own intuition is that continuously running ultrasonic piezos and sensors would drain the battery considerably more than e.g. `exp(5.24)` every second.

Comment: is "idling" == "sleeping"? Because: a CPU that just loops uses nearly as much power as one that calculates. A CPU that is put to sleep uses far, far less. If you're not using sleep modes as of now, you're totally worrying about the wrong thing, and need to learn how to use your MCU efficiently first, before caring about such details.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcusMüller. I did mean "sleeping".

Comment: I think if you don't even know what the chip is, worrying about the cost of calculating an exponential is an extreme case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 4):

> once a second

calculate/benchmar how much time that calculation takes. Wild guess: less than 200 CPU cycles. You didn't tell us *anything* about your MCU, but let's assume it runs at 1 MHz (that's far slower than modern MCUs usually run). Then, that's 2·10⁻⁴ s worth of power consumption. Does that matter to your application significantly? 
We can't tell you, because you don't tell us how much of a second your device is not in sleep. I bet it doesn't matter much.

> The precision needed is only around four significant digits

Then use a cheap power series approximation. As you know,

$$e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \cdots\text.$$

If you know the range of your \$x\$, then it's pretty easy to figure out how many elements of that sum you need to achieve your desired accuracy.

Also note that it's usual that you don't actually need \$e^x\$. Any other exponential base works too, and is just a factor away; i.e. you can use \$2^x\$, which many FPUs can give you quite trivially and energy efficient.

Other can't. We're not talking about "slightly different amounts of energy here", we're talking about fundamentally different approaches to calculating the same.

So, conclusion:

1. Nope, there's no such rough number as you hope for
2. It really depends on your hardware, and your algorithmic choices.
3. once a second is ridiculously rarely, and unless you're not building something that is otherwise extraordinarily power-efficient, will not matter.